# Error query oracle db in toad

Tags: oracle, toad

I've executed following query in toad:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTWEB.usuarios
(
  id             INTEGER  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  matricula      INTEGER,
  nome           CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  senha          CHAR(50),
  nivel          INTEGER,
  maleta         INTEGER,
  email          CHAR(50),
  acessos        INTEGER,
  datacriacao    DATE,
  dataalteracao  DATE
  UNIQUE (id)
)

LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL;
```

And got this `ORA` message:

> ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis
>   Cause: A left parenthesis has been entered without a closing right parenthesis, or extra information was contained in the parentheses. All parentheses must be entered in pairs.
>   Action: Correct the syntax and retry the statement.

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: With any SQL question, it should be a good etiquette to post the DB version up to 4 decimals. All you need to do is `select banner from v$version where rownum = 1`. And the best thing is to post a working test case, which includes, create statements, few insert statements for sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your syntax. The `NOT NULL` has to occur after the `IDENTITY` clause. The range has to be specified without a `,` and the `UNIQUE` keyword has to appear at the column directly:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTWEB.usuarios
(
  id             INTEGER  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  matricula      INTEGER,
  nome           CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  senha          CHAR(50),
  nivel          INTEGER,
  maleta         INTEGER,
  email          CHAR(50),
  acessos        INTEGER,
  datacriacao    DATE,
  dataalteracao  DATE
)
LOGGING NOCOMPRESS NOCACHE NOPARALLEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified `unique` not right, to solve it you have several ways:

First, create unique key explicitly:

```
create table tab1(
 id number(10),
 CONSTRAINT id_uk UNIQUE (id)
)
```

Second, create unique key as an option of the column:

```
create table tab1(
 id number(10) UNIQUE
)
```

Third, add the unique key constraint using `alter table`:

```
create table tab1(
 id number(10)
);
alter table tab1 add constraint id_uk unique(id);
```

Forth, create unique key implicitly by creating unique index:

```
create table tab1(
 id number(10)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_uk ON tab1 (id);
```